# How to detect collision between 2 non-axis alligned rectangles?

Tags: algorithm

I understand how to do simple collision-detection between 2 axist-alligned rectangles, however, how do I do it when one of them rotates?

Comment: Please provide more information/code relating to your question. What are you developing? Which platform are you using? Answers to these question coud help others point you out to possibly relevant libraries.....

Comment: https://www.gamedev.net/articles/programming/general-and-gameplay-programming/2d-rotated-rectangle-collision-r2604

Comment: (*Rotates*? Or "isn't axis-aligned" / iso-oriented / "rotated by something other than an integral multiple of PI/2"?) "Alligned" or not: with two simple polygons, either the edges intersect, one is contained in the other, or they don't "collide".

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the separating axis theorem.

Here's a link that describes it (or you can look up on the Internet)

http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/#sat-convex

In short it says
SAT states that: “If two convex objects are not penetrating, there exists an axis for which the projection of the objects will not overlap.”